# NullReferenceException - Need to Update Field

Tags: vb.net, exception, gridview

Been trying to update a field in the GridView but with no successful attempt.  This is the error I got **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**.  It keeps breaking at this line `dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("TicketID") = (CType(row.FindControl("TicketID"), TextBox)).ToString` Being a beginner, I've no idea how to fix this.  Any help is much appreciated.

Code-behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim dt As New DataTable("historyList")

    dt.Columns.Add("TicketID", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("DateCreated", GetType(DateTime))
    dt.Columns.Add("FullName", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("TicketType", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Subject", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Message", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Status", GetType(String))

    For i = 0 To 6
        Dim tableRow = dt.NewRow()
        tableRow("TicketID") = i
        tableRow("DateCreated") = Now()
        tableRow("FullName") = i.ToString()
        tableRow("TicketType") = i.ToString()
        tableRow("Subject") = i.ToString()
        tableRow("Message") = i.ToString()
        tableRow("Status") = i.ToString()
        dt.Rows.Add(tableRow)
    Next

    Session("dt") = dt

    BindData()

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    BindData()
End Sub
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs)
    GridView1.EditIndex = 1
    BindData()
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim dt = CType(Session("dt"), DataTable)

    'if your current DataSource be in Session
    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("TicketID") = (CType(row.FindControl("TicketID"), TextBox)).ToString
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("DateCreated") = (CType(row.FindControl("DateCreated"), TextBox)).ToString
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("FullName") = (CType(row.FindControl("FullName"), TextBox)).ToString
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("TicketType") = (CType(row.FindControl("TicketType"), TextBox)).ToString
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Subject") = (CType(row.FindControl("Subject"), TextBox)).ToString
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Message") = (CType(row.FindControl("Message"), TextBox)).ToString
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Status") = (CType(row.FindControl("Status"), TextBox)).ToString

    Session("dt") = dt
    GridView1.EditIndex = 1
    BindData()

End Sub

Private Sub BindData()

    'GridView1.DataSource = Session("dt")
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure that the value of `rows.DataItemIndex` is a valid index in your data table.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Actually, I used `rows.DataItemIndex` from an MSDN example.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the FindControl method is returning null references (if I remember correctly, I'm talking about the `nothing` value in VB). That would mean the controls aren't being stored in the row, so check that.

Comment: vb.net allows calling methods with no arguments without the parentheses

Comment: Thanks. .NET is my day to day, but I haven't touched VB in ages. Editing.

Comment: @Renan: Added the parenthesis after each call to ToString and it didn't work.  Same error message.  I then tried changing .ToString() to .Text, with no luck either.  If the controls aren't being stored in the row, is there another method to replace FindControl?

Comment: The FindControl method, when used like that, searches for a user control inside the one which had the method called. Are you sure the GridViewRow has those controls? I see in your code you commented out the part where the GridView gets its DataSource. If you hadn't done that, the gridview and the DataTable would just synchronize alright.

Comment: @Renan: Reason I commented out the DataSource is because it gave an error too - **Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition** so I chose to comment it out.

Comment: In that case, do check that the controls in the GridView have the same id's as the ones you're using in your code.